# Capture Application inactivity for certain time

Tags: swift

I am trying to find out if user does not click or scroll or any other type of events in the application for 3 min; or in other words user is not interactive in the application, then the application will sign him out. similar bank application.

I could able to add `GestureRecognizer` as follows, but I want to catch up all the activities on the UI, is there a way to handle anything like that?

Set up a `tap recognizer` on `collectionView`:

In the `viewDidLoad` add the following:

```
let collectionViewTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(collectionViewTap))
collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(collectionViewTap)
```

Declare this function which will be called when the `collectionView` is tapped:

```
func collectionViewTap() {
    print("collectionViewTap")
}
```

I could able to implement the time difference as follows to see timeDifference as well.

```
 func isUserRequiredToLogin(){
    let lastActivityDateAndTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lastActivityDateAndTime") as! Date
    let currentDate = Date()
    let minutes = currentDate.minutes(from: lastActivityDateAndTime)
    print(minutes)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer: Timer?

func resetTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timeIsOur), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc func timeIsOur() {
//logout
//log something
//alerts
}
```

you can add a Timer to your code and reset it in any event you want. If timer won't be reset - than timeIsOur will be executed and you do whatever you want - (logout or log something)
try to use this https://www.zerotoappstore.com/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-swift.html It works in my production app.